# How to have a bash script not exit on error after having used set -e?

Tags: linux, bash, exit

In a bash script, we use `set -e` to specify that from this line onwards, we want to exit on any error. But let us say, at some line I want to disable it, that is tell the bash script to no more exit on an error. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use

```
set +e
```

To revert back to the default behavior.

If it is for a single command, an idiomatic solution is to follow your command with `true` on error.

```
myfaultycommand || true
```